# Improving Mergesort. Improvement 3). Use one less copy between input and temp arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, merge

I am currently working on a project for my algorithms class and am at a bit of a standstill. We were assigned to do improvements to merge sort, that was in the book, by implementing specific changes. I have worked fine through the first 2 changes but the 3'rd one is killer.

Merge sort, the one we are improving, copies the contents of the input array into the temporary array, and then copies the temporary array back into the input array. So it recursively sorts the input array, placing the two sorted halves into the temporary array. And then it merges the two halves in the temporary array together, placing the sorted sequence into the input array as it goes.

The improvement is that this double copying is wasteful can be done without. His hint is that: We can make it so that each call to Merge only copies in one direction, but the calls to Merge alternate the direction.

This is supposedly done by  blurring the lines between the original and temporary array.

I am not really looking for code as I am confident that I can code this. I just have no idea what i'm supposed to be doing. The professor is gone for the day so I can't ask him until next week when I have his course again.

Has anyone done something like this before? Or can decipher and put it into laymans terms for me :P

The first improvement, simply has it use insertion sort whenever an Array gets small enough that it will benefit greatly, timewise, from doing so.

The second improvement stops allocating two dynamic arrays (the 2 halves that are sorted) and instead allocates 1 array of size n and that is what is used instead of the two dynamic arrays. That's that last one I did. The code for that is :

```
//#include "InsertionSort.h"
#define INSERTION_CUTOFF 250
#include <limits.h>  // needed for INT_MAX (the sentinel)
void merge3(int* inputArray, int p, int q, int r, int* tempArray)
{
  int i,j,k;
  for (i = p; i <= r; i++)
  {
    tempArray[i] = inputArray[i];
  }
  i = p;
  j = q+1;
  k = p;
  while (i <= q && j <= r)
  {
    if (tempArray[i] <= tempArray[j])
    {
      inputArray[k++] = tempArray[i++];
    }
    else
    {
      inputArray[k++] = tempArray[j++];
    }
  }
}//merge3()

void mergeSort3Helper(int* inputArray, int p, int r, int* tempArray)
{
  if (r - p < INSERTION_CUTOFF)
  {
    insertionSort(inputArray,p,r);
    return;
  }
  int q = (p+r-1)/2;
  mergeSort3Helper(inputArray,p,q,tempArray);
  mergeSort3Helper(inputArray,q+1,r,tempArray);
  merge3(inputArray,p,q,r,tempArray);
}//mergeSort3Helper()

void mergeSort3(int* inputArray, int p, int r)
{
  if (r-p < 1)
  {
    return;
  }
  if (r - p < INSERTION_CUTOFF)
  {
    insertionSort(inputArray,p,r);
    return;
  }
  int* tempArray = malloc((r-p)+1*sizeof(int));
  tempArray[r+1] = INT_MAX;
  mergeSort3Helper(inputArray,p,r,tempArray);
//  This version of merge sort should allocate all the extra space
//  needed for merging just once, at the very beginning, instead of
//  within each call to merge3().
}//mergeSort3()
```

Comment: I am assuming that the the book has code/pseudo-code for this algorithm. Could you post that?

Comment: Well, the 3 other improvements to merge sort that I have already done, do go very far away from the original merge sort. So the idea is that we are supposed to use the previous improvement as a starting point for this one. So I will post the previous improvement.

Comment: Err, sorry, the other 2 improvements. Typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm is like this:
A1: 7 0 2 9 5 1 4 3
A2: (uninitialized)

Step 1:
A1 : unchanged
A2: 0 7 2 9 1 5 3 4

Step 2:
A1: 0 2 7 9 1 3 4 5
A2: unchanged

Step 3:
A1: unchanged
A2: 0 1 2 3 4 5 7 9

This involves you copying only one way each time and follows the steps of mergesort. As your professor said, you blur the lines between the work array and the sorted array by alternating which is which, and only copying once things are sorted.

Comment: Alright that helps me understand this a lot better but my confusion now lies as, where do I copy? See, we are given, as a hint supposedly, 3 sections in the file we are working on. One is mergeSort4 (because mergesort1 is just the stand mergesort). Then we have mergeSort4Helper and merge4.

Now the last merge sort I did, which I posted but i'll get to the important bit, I malloced the temp array in mergeSort3, Recursively sorted input arra mergeSort3Helper and in there called merge3 to copy the input array into temp, merged the 2 halves of inputArray in temp, and copied back to temp.

Comment: I don't see where I can have it start alternating. I get the idea, I do, but I don't see which copying is the one I'm supposed to give up, or where i'm supposed to give up on.

Also, wouldn't a problem arise with odd numbered arrays? Where it could possible not make that last alternation to put back into the input array? Or should I have a condition to return either the input array or temp array depending on that?

Comment: Finally, I'm using a call to insertionSort to actually do the recursive sorting, (Not the merging of the 2 sorted halves, just getting those 2 halves sorted to begin with is what i'm using insertionSort for).

Comment: @neojb1989 You simply swap the addresses of inputArray and tempArray. Therefore, if at recursion level i, you get array one as inputArray and array two as tempArray, you swap them and feed it to the next level so that it would see array two as inputArray and array one as tempArray. However, since it is receiving them through the inputArray and tempArray pointers, it has no idea they are swapped and therefore works without a change

Comment: Thank you for the help, it helped me complete it :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it would be difficult and ultimately unprofitable to avoid *all* copying.  What you want to do instead is to avoid the copy you currently do with each merge.

Your current `merge3(inputArray, p,q,r, tempArray)` returns the merged result in its original array, which requires a copy; it uses its `tempArray` buffer only as a resource.  In order to do better, you need to modify it to something like `merge4(inputArray, p,q,r, outputArray)`, where the result is returned in the second buffer, not the first.

You will need to change the logic in `mergeSort3Helper()` to deal with this.  One approach requires a comparable interface change, to `mergeSort4Helper(inputArray, p,q,r, outputArray)`, such that it also yields its result in its second buffer.  This will require a copy at the lowest (insertion sort) level, and a second copy in the top-level `mergeSort4()` if you want your final result in the same buffer it came in.  However, it eliminates all other unnecessary copies.

Alternately, you could add a boolean parameter to `mergeSort4Helper()` to indicate whether you want the result returned in the first or second buffer.  This value would alternate recursively, resulting in at most one copy, at the lowest level.

A final option might be to do the merging non-recursively, and alternate buffers at each pass.  This would also result in at most one copy; however, I would expect the resulting access pattern to be inherently less cache-friendly than the recursive one.

Comment: Can't seem to wrap my head around this. I appreciate the try and there is effort in there, but I am bound to the function parameters the prof wrote for us. I'm assuming he wants us to find his way of solving it, or as close as we can to it.

Comment: You can probably stretch the definition of "tempArray" to be an output array, and implement my first solution that way...

Comment: What your saying is just have like:
return outputArray
instead of returning the inputArray?

Cause i've thought of that but i think he wants us to always return the inputArray.